# The dimension of a subspace is less than dimension of the whole space.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be topological space and $Y\subset X$. The goal is to show that $\dim Y\leq \dim X$.

Here we use this definition of dimension.

Let $Y_0\subsetneq Y_1\subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq Y_{n}$ be a chain of strictly increasing closed irreducible subsets of $X$ then $\dim X$ is the supremum over all such chains.

This is what I've got so far. I'm just stuck on one last bit. A hint would be nice.

Let $Y_0\subsetneq Y_1\subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq Y_n$ be a chain of irreducible closed subsets of $Y$. Since each $Y_i$ is irreducible, we just need to close them in $X$. There exists $F_i$ closed in $X$ such that $Y_i=F_i\cap Y$. Then if we closed each set in $X$, $\overline{F_0\cap Y}\subset\overline{F_1\cap Y}\subset \cdots \subset \overline{F_n\cap Y}$ is a chain of irreducible closed subsets of $X$. I just need to show that they are distinct. I really don't know where to proceed. A hint would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to use as much of what you've done as I can.

You want to know that $\overline{Y_i} \subsetneq \overline{Y_{i+1}}$. Can I find points in the latter but not the former? Yes; I claim the points of $Y_{i+1} \setminus Y_i$ will work. Find me a closed set in $X$ that contains $Y_i$ but misses all of the points in this difference. You've already written one down.

Something you can prove in the same way is that if $S$ is a subset of $Y$ then $\operatorname{cl}_Y(S) = \operatorname{cl}_X(S) \cap Y$. That's comforting.

Comment: I don't see the space set you are talking about. $Y$ is not necessarily closed in $X$ so $F_{i}\cap Y$ is not necessarily closed. Was I supposed to look for something else?

Comment: Took a different approach but your hint helped. Thanks.

Comment: @user90401 I was referring to your $F_i$. This is a closed set in $X$, it contains $Y_i$, and its intersection with $Y$ is exactly $Y_i$, so it doesn't contain $Y_{i+1}$.